# Libreria PHP Modbus

Tags: php, tcp, modbus

estoy empezando con el uso de esta libreria, aun no entiendo mucho sobre como se utiliza, estoy usando las direcciones 40001 y 40002 para leer informacion pero no tengo idea de como debo colocar estos datos en la funcion **readMultipleRegisters** , podria alguien indicarme como hacerlo , muchas gracias.
Les dejo el codigo que estoy utilizando

```php
    
    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../Phpmodbus/ModbusMaster.php';
    
    // Create Modbus object
    $modbus = new ModbusMaster("192.168.1.190", "TCP");
    
    try {
      
       $recData = $modbus->readMultipleRegisters(1, 0x40000, 5);
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        // Print error information if any
        echo $modbus;
        echo $e;
        exit;
    }
    
    // Print status information
    echo "</br>Status:</br>" . $modbus;
    
    // Print read data
    echo "</br>Data:</br>";
    print_r($recData); 
    echo "</br>";
```